# Eclipse is taking more CPU

Tags: eclipse, cpu-usage

[image]

As in above image, eclipse is taking more CPU which causing more time to work with eclipse.
How to optimize the eclipse CPU usage to be normal.

Comment: What Eclipse version? What type of project? How many projects may be open if there are multiple?

Comment: Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) and 10 maven projects